# Transparent image plane doesn't show whole image

Tags: rendering, materials, image, transparency, texture-baking

I imported a PNG Image Plane, wich Looks like this:
[image: PNG Image]

Then I changed the material, so it's transparent.

Nodes:
[image: Nodes]

But the rendered result Looks like this:
[image: Render Result]

Some parts are missing or they became transparent. Can someone please help me. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second mix shader should be driven by the *alpha* channel instead of the color. As it stands, "bright" colors will be rendered opaque but the darker branches are transparent. This obviously depends on your image including a proper alpha channel.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the bottom right nodes, where you're multiplying the image as displacement. For just rendering a plane with transparent parts, you don't need displacement.

Additionally, connect the Alpha from your image texture to the factor of your mix shader, not the color dot.